# How to cache webpack's assets and exclude index.html?

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I want to optimize my SPA to cache all of webpack's assets so they load faster on next reload.

I don't need offline capabilities and I want the users to always be served the new versions on as soon as they reload the page, no "New content is available; please refresh." message.

For what I understand, Webpack is including hashes in the name of each files so file names are "unique" from one version to another. So my strategy is to cache everything besides `index.html`. So when a user hits reload, he always gets the `index.html` from the server and then service workers serves cache for already loaded files.

Put simply, I am looking to replicate a simple caching like with header Cache-Control.

Should I use the `workbox-webpack-plugin` and the `GenerateSW(config)` method ? How to configure it to exclude only `index.html` from the cache and include everything else ?

Answer (score 1):

The `workbox-webpack-plugin` has the exclude option that you can use to exclude `index.html`.

More information can be found here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW#GenerateSW